# Указать шрифт до загрузки css

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице есть текст, шрифт которого до загрузки и применения css является не таким, каким требуется. Как можно задать требуемый шрифт для текста, который бы применялся до того, как будут загружены стили?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `<link rel="stylesheet" href="YOUR_URL">`. Например:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Other CSS -->
</head>
```